Delete elements of a nested list which are duplicate as sets
Suppose I have a (nested) list of subsets of $4×4$ matrices, each subset containing the same number of matrices, say $3$ here (for simplicity).
Note that these are sets in reality but because they are stored as arrays, if two subsets have same $3$ matrices but in different order they don't get recognised as duplicates, I mean I'm unable to get mathematica to do that. Suppose I have the following input:
data={{M1,M2,M3},{M2,M5,M4},{M3,M1,M2},{M3,M2,M1},{M5,M2,M4},{M5,M6,M7}}

(These Mi's actually appear like this: {{....},{....},{....},{....}} in the nested list not as variable names.
The output I would like, is
res={{M1,M2,M3},{M2,M5,M4},{M5,M6,M7}}

The order in which these sets appear in the res does not matter nor does the order of matrices inside data.
Question: How do I delete elements which are duplicate as sets?
(This thing runs inside loop so please consider that. The process needs to be time-efficient. My intersection method was not efficient at all.)

note that you can not write List= since List is protected.  It will also be much easier to help you if you give an actual input, with the output you want. Instead of saying These Mi's actually appear like this: {{....},{....},{....},{....}} in the nested list not as variable names. and have the person who will answer make and figure what these are supposed to be.

DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, Sort] would do it.

@Nasser sorry, that was first letter capitalisation typo., it was 'list'. I posted the question from my phone. About Mi's , those are just $4×4$ matrices (2 dimensional list would be more precise). I didn't know if I was supposed to give exact entries.

If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory book written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a fast intro for math students as well as a fast intro for programmers to choose from.

@Syed Thank you. But I don't have DeleteDuplicatesBy command in Mathematica 9.0

Is the command DeleteDuplicates[S, Sort[#1] === Sort[#2] &] exact alternative of what you wrote above?
